# Django website deployment is raising an ImproperlyConfigured error

Tags: django, python-3.x, cpanel

I am configuring a new Django web site using Cpanel. After completing the whole procedures and run this code `python manage.py collectstatic` I am getting the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/massvnrc/virtualenv/mysite/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/massvnrc/virtualenv/mysite/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/massvnrc/virtualenv/mysite/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 195, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/home/massvnrc/virtualenv/mysite/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 40, in load_command_class
    return module.Command()
  File "/home/massvnrc/virtualenv/mysite/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 32, in __init__
    self.storage.path('')
  File "/home/massvnrc/virtualenv/mysite/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 48, in path
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("You're using the staticfiles app "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.
```

Bellow is the configuration that is raising the error:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=[BASE_DIR+"/assets",]
MEDIA_ROOT='/home/****/public_html/media'
STATIC_ROOT='/home/****/public_html/static'
```

I honestly don't know where is the erro and the similar issues do not help me to solve the problem.

Please assist me

Comment: Are you getting this error in localhost?

Comment: where you have 4 asterisks in your path is this done to mask your user on here or are you trying to use it as a NIX style wild card?

Comment: I used asterisks to not have a long path but here is the full and correct path that I am using. MEDIA_ROOT='/home/massvnrc/public_html/media' and STATIC_ROOT='/home/massvnrc/public_html/static'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I am seeing in your code you need to add **STATIC_ROOT=' '** in your settings.py
What **python manage.py collectstatic** do is to collect the static files from the directory.

put your static files folder into your app folder.

I have encountered the same error.Therefore,I suggest you to give your static files path first and then run the collectstatic command again.

Here is the procedure:

**Step1:** Put your static files into your project app folder first.

**Step2:** Add this STATIC_ROOT='path where you want to collect those static files'

## where do you want to extract those static files.

If the issue persists or you need more help feel free to comment

Comment: Please I don't get it very. From what I have done you can help me STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
STATIC_ROOT=''
STATICFILES=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'/home/massvnrc/massiwa_website/static')

Comment: This is the media root path: MEDIA_ROOT='/home/massvnrc/massiwa_website/media'

Comment: Put your static files folder into your app first and make STATIC_ROOT="path where you want to extract your static files" and then just run collectstatic command. Remove **STATICFILES** from **STATIC_ROOT** .

Comment: **STATIC_URL = '/static/'** 
**STATIC_ROOT='/home/django/django_project/django_project/static'** Do not use staticfiles inside **STATIC_ROOT**

Answer (score 1):

In settings, the proper configuration for static would like this

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '' #This tell where the static file location inside static dirs. Empty means current
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), #Note this is tuple, and path is /home/../DjangoFolder/static
)
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Your file structure is like

```
DjangoProject #(This is the BASE_DIR path)
 |-manage.py
 |-Django app folder
 |-static #<- you created this folder
 |-media #<- you created this folder
```

As much as you can avoid using paths as a string as there can be issues while migrating to production. Instead, use 'os' library to get the current directory path. Usually, all folders are accessible from BASE_DIR if you configure it like documented in Django.

Comment: I have tried what you suggested but still, I am getting the same error. Please have a look at what I have done: STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT=''
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT='/home/massvnrc/public_html/media'
STATICFILES_DIRS=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'/home/massvnrc/public_html/static')

Comment: You are almost there @MohamedAbdillah just copy the code and maintain the directory structure like I did and your problem should be solved.

Comment: still does not work. I followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ffqMZ5IcmSY